# Next.js 13.4.x file upload

Tags: file-upload, next.js13

I'm trying to upload binary data with the latest version of Next.js, at the time of writing is 13.4.9. I've tried [busboy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/busboy) and [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) to no avail. It seems the [Next request object](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/next-request) is a bit different than the [Node Request object](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#class-httpclientrequest), so the online examples are no longer working, and I don't want to write a custom express server...

Here's what I have; there are no errors, but multer is not reading the uploaded file or textual data:

**Client**

```js
'use client';

import { useRef } from 'react'

export default function SampleUpload() {
    const fileRef = useRef(null);
    return (
    <div>
        <input id="fileInput" type="file" name="file" ref={fileRef} />
        <button onClick={() => {
            const formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('audio', fileRef.current.files[0]);
            const jsonData = {
                sampleRate: 44100,
            };
            formData.append("data", JSON.stringify(jsonData));
            fetch('/api/upload', {
                method: 'POST',
                body: formData,
            }).then(response => {
                if (response.ok) {
                    return response.json();
                }
                throw new Error('Network response was not ok.');
            }).then(data => {
                console.log(data);
            }).catch(error => {
                console.error('There was a problem with the fetch operation:', error.message);
            });
        }}>Upload</button>
    </div>
    )
}
```

**Server**

```js
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
const multer = require('multer');

const storage = multer.memoryStorage(); // store the file as buffer in memory
const upload = multer({ storage: storage });

// This produces a warning, but I can't find the appropriate way to do it here
// https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/route-segment-config
export const config = {
    api: {
        bodyParser: false,
    },
};

export async function POST(req: Request) {
    const res = new NextResponse('success', { status: 200 });

    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        upload.single('audio')(req, res, (err) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve();
            }
        });
    });

    // There are no errors, but neither req.file nor req.body are set by now...
    console.log('file? ', req.file)
    console.log('body? ', req.body)
    
    return res;
}
```

Comment: I'm also digging through the [next examples](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/068002bb3a294368de9ef62f8831fe7177f27a61/examples), but haven't found anything.

Comment: It looks like [Server Actions](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/server-actions) is the way to handle file uploads now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the experimental [Server Actions](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/server-actions) feature is the only way to achieve this now, because you can no longer override the Next server. Tune the `accept` attribute to your needs.

**next.config.js**

```js
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
    experimental: {
        serverActions: true,
    },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

**Client**

```js
'use client'
import uploadFile from '@/actions/uploadFile';

export default function FileUploader() {
    return (
    <form action={uploadFile}>
        <div>Choose an audio file:</div>
        <input type="file" id="myFile" name="myFile" accept="audio/*" />
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
    </form>);
}
```

**Server**

```js
'use server'

export default async function uploadFile(formData: FormData) {
    const _formData = {};

    // _formData.myFile holds the file contents
    for(let [key, value] of formData.entries()) {
        _formData[key] = value;
    }
}
```